# AS3: Is it possible to create a variable to hold instance name?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to have a more dynamic function and would like to allow the functions instance name were it outputs the text to be changeable.

for example

```
function example_function(url,instance_name){
      instance_name.text = url;
}

example_function('www.example.com','url_txt');
example_function('www.another.com','more_txt');
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just parse the string into square brackets next to the instance's owner. For example:

```
this[instance_name].text = url;
```

More info:

Take this object:

```
var obj:Object = {
    property1: 10,
    property2: "hello"
};
```

Its properties can be accessed either as you'd expect:

```
obj.property1;
obj.property2;
```

Or as mentioned above:

```
obj["property1"];
obj["property2"];
```

I suggest using a function like this one I've created to tighten your code up a bit:

```
function selectProperty(owner:*, property:String):*
{
    if(owner.hasOwnProperty(property)) return owner[property];
    else throw new Error(owner + " does not have a property \"" + property + "\".");

    return null;
}

trace(selectProperty(stage, "x")); // 0
trace(selectProperty(stage, "test")); // error
```

Comment: And how would this work for something that was inside another MC for example mc.instance_name.text = url; would it be this[mc].this[instance_name].text = url;??

Comment: @Eli.Stone If you're already in the same scope as `mc` you can do this: `mc[instance_name].text = url;`

Comment: @Eli.Stone That depends entirely on how your class can access `mc`. If `mc` is a property of your class then my previous comment is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible, but it's not really best practice to do it with Strings like that. Instead, you can pass in a reference to the variable you're trying to modify.

```
function example_function(url : String, instance : TextField) : void {
    instance.text = url;
}

example_function("www.example.com", url_txt);
```

This gives you strong typing so you can tell at compile time if you're operating on a TextField or not. If you aren't, you'll get an error because the 'text' property doesn't exist. You'll be able to find and track down errors faster this way.

However, if you must do it with Strings, you can access any property on any object using a string key like:

```
var myInstance = this[instance_name]
```

So in your example, you could do:

```
function example_function(url : String, instance : TextField) : void {
    this[instance_name].text = url;
}

example_function("www.example.com", "url_txt");
```